# Unable to mount Windows Server 2008 share from Linux (fedora13)

Tags: linux, mount, fedora, windows-server-2008, nfs

I am trying to mount a shared drive on a Windows Server 2008 machine using a Linux machine (Fedora 13).
I try mounting by

#### # `mount //HOSTNAME/SHARENAME /mnt/FOLDER`

and I get `mount error(13): Permission denied`.

I have tried other options like `# mount -t nfs //HOSTNAME/SHARENAME /mnt/FOLDER -o username=USERNAME` and the same thing with different filesystem types (ntfs, smbfs, cifs).

I have:

- checked all firewall configurations.
- verified security/sharing settings
  for the drive
- verified registry keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NfsSvr\Parameters`
- verified NFS server is running

I am familiar with Windows Server 2008 but I have never configured a system from scratch on my own.
The computer I'm using used to have Windows 7 for sharing folders to a Linux server.  I have just switched to Server 2008 and have not been able to mount anymore.

One thing that I think is that I tried setting up an identity mapping solution; however, I do not have a domain controller setup.  I am still functioning on a workgroup.  I selected anonymous but still no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you chose NFS rather than CIFS (aka WIndows Networking) as the share method?  Windows with CIFS shares to Linux systems works pretty transparently - especially with gnome or kde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bouncing the Linux server, everything functioned as normal...
Doh!


I guess the previous mounts just needed to be cycled.  Although I foolishly did not try, I'm sure that simply using the **umount** command or removing the directories/re-creating them would have sufficed.